# How change language in Swagger-UI using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

How change language to pt-br in Swagger-UI using Swashbuckle?

I'm add in SwaggerConfig:

```
 .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    c.InjectJavaScript(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "{appnamespace}.Content.js.translator.js", false);
                    c.InjectJavaScript(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "{appnamespace}.Content.js.pt.js", false);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works to me according to the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#customization-36), in ASP.NET Core, for example, you must add the path in InjectOnCompleteJavaScript method.

```
c.InjectOnCompleteJavaScript("/swagger/lang/translator.js");
c.InjectOnCompleteJavaScript("/swagger/lang/custom.js");
```

The custom.js is my customized file obtained by swagger UI em production according to the path of the swagger UI in your application. My file is custom because I've executed `window.SwaggerTranslator.translate()` after learn method has been executed.

Comment: In Asp.net Core 2.1 i'm using:

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
        c.HeadContent = "<script src='/js/pt.js'></script>";
});